# Adding rows to table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My button and table is as shown,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-md" id="addRowBtn">Test Button To Add Row</button>
<table id="tableForRows">
     <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to keep adding text boxes on click of button..My jquery is as shown,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addRowBtn").on("click", function () {
        var tableRow = $("#tableForRows").html();
        var itemToAdd = "<tr><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>";
       $("#tableForRows").append(itemToAdd);
    });
});
```

Help me know what the right way is..Thanks in advance..

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: This is a typo with your quotes. The syntax highlighting in your question shows that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have quotation problem, use single quotes for `type='text'`:

```
"<tr><td><input type='text'/></td></tr>";
```

Also, based on what you shared, `var tableRow = $("#tableForRows").html();` is redundant.

Comment: To add to this, you can also use `"<tr><td><input type=\"text\"/></td></tr>";`. Using backslashes will escape the quote character.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addRowBtn").click(function () {
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        $("#tableForRows").append(tr);
        $("#tableForRows tr:last-child").append(td);
        $("#tableForRows tr:last-child td:last-child").append(input);
    });
});
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Neoares/Lo6p02oc/

Comment: You should add the input to the `td`, then the `td` to the `tr`, then the `tr` to the table. It will save you the last three selectors, which can be quite slow. Something like: https://jsfiddle.net/Lo6p02oc/2/